# Halting Execution of a program in C#

Tags: c#

In C++, I used to write a function that stops the execution of the program by the amount of the float parameter passed to it, there's the function:

```
void wait(float sec){
  clock_t endwait = clock() + sec * CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // CLOCK_PER_SEC == 1000
  while(clock() < endwait);
}
```

is there an equivalent built in method in C# like that ?
if not, how can i write one like that in C# ?

Thnx in advance .. :)

Comment: Your C++ wait method is awful.  It will consume as many cycles as possible.  Instead, call sleep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please use `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(int millisecondsTimeout);`

Answer (score 3):

> Thread.Sleep(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

is equivalent method with

> void wait(float sec)

But, it is not halting the execution of program. It is just suspending the thread which the program running on. I think there is a little difference between these methods. `void wait(float sec)`is a busy wait method. The processor takes the thread or process from active process queue, does some calculation. But in method `Thread.Sleep(CLOCKS_PER_SEC)` thread goes to Suspend queue, the processor doesn't take it to run unless CLOCKS_PER_SEC time ended.

Answer (score 2):

```
Thread.Sleep(CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

or

```
Thread.SpinWait(NUMBER_OF_CYCLES);
```

**--EDIT--**

My apologies folks. Had a power cut as I was writing my explanation for the above... that will teach me to post half an answer to try to be the first.  Thanks to the commenters keeping things in check.  :).

Anyway... `Thread.Sleep` will pause the current thread for a period of time while `Thread.SpinWait` will cause the thread to go into a tight loop (from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.spinwait.aspx)).

An interesting way to compare `Thread.Sleep` with `Thread.SpinWait` is to monitor the processor activity with something like Task Manager.  If you view the Task Manager while running the following

```
Thread.SpinWait(int.MaxValue);
```

you will notice that the process maxes out one of the cores while that line of code is running.  If you run the following line, however,

```
Thread.Sleep(int.MaxValue);
```

you will notice that the process does not use any processing cycles at all.

Comment: Thread.Sleep and Thread.SpinWait are not interchangeable (as someone might get an impression), besides that, Thread.Sleep uses milliseconds as parameter and Thread.SpinWait uses number of iterations.

Comment: @VeXe To answer your question (which I'm sure you already have the answer to by now) it is in `System.Threading`.